# Firebase Firestore Functions get data from wildcards and then write data in another collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from the wildcards and then update a notification collection in my database. I was just wondering if there is any way to get root doc data from the wildcards as well and to update the message collection.

```
exports.likedByWho = functions.firestore.document('Posts/{postID}/{likeCollection}/{userWhoLikedID}')
    .onWrite((event) => { 
        console.log(event.params.postID);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.params.likeCollection);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.params.userWhoLikedID);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.data.data());
        ^^^^^works but gives data of userWhoLikedID doc
        //console.log(`${event.params.feedID.data().uploadedBy}`);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Get user id of the person who posted this post.
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^How to access root doc area.        


admin.firestore().collection("Posts").doc(`${event.params.postID}`).get().then(docData => console.log(docData.data()));
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^is there another way of doing this using event.ref maybe


        return;
    });
```

To write in the message collection, can I use `event.ref` or `admin.firestore()`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What you do you mean by "root doc data"?

Comment: Well I have a Collection called Posts which has doc called PostID which has a subcollection called Likes which has a doc called LikeID. Now the above function triggers when someone writes to the Likes SubCollection and it gives the data of the LikeID doc. I was wondering if I can get the data of the PostID doc as well from the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that document's data using the admin SDK:

```
exports.likedByWho = functions.firestore.document('Posts/{postID}/{likeCollection}/{userWhoLikedID}')
    .onWrite((event) => { 
        console.log(event.params.postID);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.params.likeCollection);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.params.userWhoLikedID);
        ^^^^^works
        console.log(event.data.data());
        ^^^^^works but gives data of userWhoLikedID doc
        //console.log(`${event.params.feedID.data().uploadedBy}`);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Get user id of the person who posted this post.
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^How to access root doc area.        

         var postRef = admin.firestore().collection('Posts')
                            .doc(event.params.postID);
         postRef.get().then(function(doc){
            console.log(doc.data());
            //data of the doc
         });

        return;
    });
```